# It gives me an error when I run a project after saving that has a template: "Debugging is not enabled"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

guys.

1. When I create an ASP.NET project in VB, I use a template for design.
2. The project without being saved yet, I run it and shows well.
3. So, when I save the project, I try to run it again, and throws the following message:

> The page cannot be run in debug mode because debugging is not enabled
>   in the web.config file

Here is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/error404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The web.config file is loaded with the template.
What is wrong?

Comment: Could you show the screen shot of right click on Web Project > Properties >  Web tab?

Comment: Debug attribute in web.config has been set true. So, can you please check debug attribute value in @page directive for the aspx page you are trying to debug?

Comment: Hi, @Vicky. I checked the attribute, and did not. I put the attribute and still does not work. Another idea?

Comment: Hi, @Win. I think I can not do that. Once I did, and they closed the question. Is there any property in special I should check?

Comment: @Morquecho.String What do you mean `they closed the question`? You can update your question anytime. Currently, I do not see any closing vote on your question. Besides, we don't normally cast vote unless question is a duplicate or some other reason.

Comment: @Morquecho.String I am not sure but you can give a try. Right click on your solution. Clean. Rebuild. Or you go to your solution folder, delete .pdb extension file if there.

Comment: Yes, because I put external links. But anyway, here is a screenshot of my web tab. Is in spanish: http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/ngfhnfhg-1660630.jpg

Comment: @Vicky I did all you write and nothing. Still not working. When I make the template, I selected the normal project where already has a predefined design of ASP.NET; Maybe, if I start the template with a ASP.NET empty project...